# Are the C++ cast operators a library

Tags: c++, casting

I know about C++ casts are operators, my question is are that casts included in a library, or are they a library for themselves?

Comment: Casts are not operators. A cast is an explicit conversion. That you use the word `operator` for defining conversion functions is mostly a way to avoid adding any more keywords to the language.

Answer (score 3):

Casts aren't part of a library, nor are they a library. The casts are part of the language itself.

Comment: Except C++20 [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) only exists in `<bit>`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Sure, but that's technically not a cast operator at all, but rather a function template.